# List of different types?

Tags: haskell

```
data Plane = Plane { point :: Point, normal :: Vector Double }
data Sphere = Sphere { center :: Point, radius :: Double }

class Shape s where
    intersect :: s -> Ray -> Maybe Point
    surfaceNormal :: s -> Point -> Vector Double
```

I have also made both `Plane` and `Sphere` instances of `Shape`.

I'm trying to store spheres and planes in the same list, but it doesn't work.  I understand that it shouldn't work because `Sphere` and `Plane` are two different types, but they are both instances of `Shape`, so shouldn't it work?  How would I store shapes and planes in a list?

```
shapes :: (Shape t) => [t]
shapes = [ Sphere { center = Point [0, 0, 0], radius = 2.0 },
         Plane { point = Point [1, 2, 1], normal = 3 |> [0.5, 0.6, 0.2] }
         ]
```

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections

Comment: I was aware of heterogeneous collections, but it's something that I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This problem represents a turning point between object-oriented and functional thinking.  Sometimes even sophisticated Haskellers are still in this mental transition, and their designs often fall into the [existential typeclass](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) pattern, mentioned in Thomas's answer.

A functional solution to this problem involves reifying the typeclass into a data type (usually once this is done, the need for the typeclass vanishes):

```
data Shape = Shape {
    intersect :: Ray -> Maybe Point,
    surfaceNormal :: Point -> Vector Double
}
```

Now you can easily construct a list of `Shape`s, because it is a monomorphic type.  Because Haskell does not support downcasting, no information is lost by removing the representational distinction between `Plane`s and `Sphere`s. The specific data types become functions that construct `Shape`s:

```
plane :: Point -> Vector Double -> Shape
sphere :: Point -> Double -> Shape
```

If you cannot capture everything you need to know about a shape in the `Shape` data type, you can enumerate the cases with an algebraic data type, as Thomas suggested.  But I would recommend against that if possible; instead, try to find the essential characteristics of a shape that you need rather than just listing off examples.

Comment: This nicely put that we should not think of Type classes as OO inheritance or interfaces and think of them subtype. They are just a set of functions that a type can support

Comment: What if you needed to typecheck whether something was a plane or sphere? Then would you suggest the ADT style?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I'd probably make a `data Sphere` that has the needed properties of a sphere, `data Plane` that has the needed properties of a plane, and then injection functions like `toShape :: Sphere -> Shape`.  Maybe put it in a `class ToShape` (as an afterthought)

Comment: How would that allow you to put Sphere and Plane in the same list?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, it wouldn't. It would allow you to put their corresponding `Shape`s into a list though, which is just the same. See http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/ for why.

Comment: But what if I wanted to keep them as spheres and planes? Would there be a corresponding function like toSphere :: Shape -> Sphere and toPlane :: Shape -> Plane to convert them back into their respective shapes?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, you mean `toSphere :: Shape -> Maybe Sphere`, because it might not have come from a `Sphere`.  While this is tempting, especially for OO programmers, it is almost always unnecessary.  It can be done with `Data.Dynamic` and similar tricks, but I recommend seeing how far you can get without it -- you might discover a lot about the problem you are trying to solve.  Read the link -- it explores exactly this problem.

Answer (score 27):

You are looking for a heterogeneous list, which most Haskellers don't particularly like even though they've asked themselves this same question when first learning Haskell.

You write:

```
shapes :: (Shape t) => [t]
```

This says the list has type `t`, all of which are the same and happen to be a Shape (the same shape!).  In other words - no, it shouldn't work how you have it.

Two common ways to handle it (a Haskell 98 way first, then a fancier way that I don't recommend second) are:

**Use a new type** to statically union the subtypes of interest:

```
data Foo = F deriving Show
data Bar = B deriving Show

data Contain = CFoo Foo | CBar Bar deriving Show
stuffExplicit :: [Contain]
stuffExplicit = [CFoo F, CBar B]

main = print stuffExplicit
```

This is nice seeing as it's straight forward and you don't lose any information about what is contained in the list.  You can determine the first element is a `Foo` and the second element is a `Bar`.  The drawback, as you probably already realize, is that you must explicitly add each component type by making a new `Contain` type constructor.  If this is undesirable then keep reading.

**Use Existential Types**: Another solution involves losing information about the elements - you just retain, say, knowledge that the elements are in a particular class.  As a result you can only use operations from that class on the list elements.  For example, the below will only remember the elements are of the `Show` class, so the only thing you can do to the elements is use functions that are polymorphic in `Show`:

```
data AnyShow = forall s. Show s => AS s

showIt (AS s) = show s

stuffAnyShow :: [AnyShow]
stuffAnyShow = [AS F, AS B]

main = print (map showIt stuffAnyShow)
```

This requires some extensions to the Haskell language, namely `ExplicitForAll` and `ExistentialQuantification`.  We had to define `showIt` explicitly (using pattern matching to deconstruct the `AnyShow` type) because you can't use field names for data types that use existential quantification.

There are more solutions (hopefully another answer will use `Data.Dynamic` - if no one does and you are interested then read up on it and feel free to post any questions that reading generates).

Comment: The first method is the very first thing I tried, and it didn't work out well.  I'm not sure if I like the second method!  I would also like to avoid using extensions.