# Memoization and typeclasses

Tags: haskell, memoization

To keep it simple, I'll use this contrived example class (the point is that we have some expensive data derived from the methods):

```
class HasNumber a where
  getNumber :: a -> Integer
  getFactors :: a -> [Integer]
  getFactors a = factor . getNumber
```

Of course, we can make memoizing implementations of this class such as:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  fooName :: String,
  fooNumber :: Integer,
  fooFactors :: [Integer]
}

foo :: String -> Integer -> Foo
foo a n = Foo a n (factor n) 

instance HasNumber Foo where
    getNumber = fooNumber
    getFactors = fooFactors
```

But it seems a bit ugly to be required to manually add a 'factors' field to any record that will be a `HasNumber` instance. Next idea:

```
data WithFactorMemo a = WithFactorMemo {
    unWfm :: a,
    wfmFactors :: [Integer]
}

withFactorMemo :: HasNumber a => a -> WithFactorMemo a
withFactorMemo a = WithFactorMemo a (getFactors a)

instance HasNumber a => HasNumber (WithFactorMemo a) where
    getNumber = getNumber . unWfm
    getFactors = wfmFactors
```

This will require lots of boilerplate for lifting all the other operations of the original `a` into `WithFactorMemo a`, though.

Are there any elegant solutions?

Comment: Another solution I just thought of would be to make the *factor* function memoizing, though this would be less practical if the result of `getNumber` was some larger data structure, and (AFAIK) the entries would never get garbage collected (in contrast to the two solutions in my question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution: lose the typeclass.  I have talked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787317/list-of-different-types/7787730#7787730) and [here](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).  Any typeclass `TC a` for which each of its members take a single `a` as an argument is isomorphic to a data type.  That means that every instance of your `HasNumber` class can be represented in this data type:

```
data Number = Number {
    getNumber' :: Integer,
    getFactors' :: [Integer]
}
```

Namely, by this transformation:

```
toNumber :: (HasNumber a) => a -> Number
toNumber x = Number (getNumber x) (getFactors x)
```

And `Number` is obviously an instance of `HasNumber` as well.

```
instance HasNumber Number where
    getNumber = getNumber'
    getFactors = getFactors'
```

This isomorphism shows us that this class is a data type in disguise, and it should die.  Just use `Number` instead.  It may be initially non-obvious how to do this, but with a little experience should come quickly. Eg., your `Foo` type becomes:

```
data Foo = Foo {
    fooName :: String,
    fooNumber :: Number
}
```

Your memoization will then come for free, because the factors are stored in the `Number` data structure.

Comment: Actually, this is what I decided to try out too just before you posted :) I agree with putting the operations into a single type (`Number` here), but maybe it's still a good idea to have a `class HasNumber a where numberDict :: a -> Number` together with wrappers `getNumber = getNumber' . numberDict` and so on. But one has to actually store the `Number` in the records which are to be `HasNumber`, rather than creating a `Number` from an Integer in the `numberDict` implementation (which would, of course, leave us without memoization again).

Comment: I highly recommend against the typeclass in cases like this, it will only get in your way.  Just model it concretely, the FP toolbox is more well-suited to that kind of programming, the language is better at abstracting over data types than typeclasses, and it doesn't let you deceive yourself that you are doing OO modeling (which you are not -- and if you are thinking that way, even without realizing it, the language will end up limiting you down the road).