# OO classes represented in Haskell

Tags: oop, haskell

H!

Suppose I have an abstract class Robot with a few attributs like 'position' and 'weight'. This abstract class implements three methods : 'take', 'drop' and 'move', but also has an abstract method 'makeAction'. Then I have two subclasses of 'Robot' named 'TRobot' and 'FRobot'. Basically, TRobot and FRobot will implement 'makeAction' method, but won't reimplement 'take', 'drop' and 'move'.

My question is how do you do this in Haskell.
I started with the datatype :

```
data Robot = Robot {position :: Char, weight :: Int}
```

EDIT :
But I want the functions 'take', 'move' and 'drop' (take :: Box -> Robot -> Robot) to behave the same if Robot is TRobot or FRobot.
However, the function

```
makeAction :: Robot -> Action
```

should have a different implementation whether Robot is TRobot or FRobot.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a *lot* of ways to do this in Haskell, but you must first understand that traditional "classes" do not directly correspond to any Haskell construct.

You can do something like this very easily:

```
data Robot = Robot {
    position :: Char,
    weight :: Int,
    makeAction :: Robot -> String
}
```

Here, `makeAction` is a field containing a different function for `TRobot` and `FRobot` types.  There are a lot of more sophisticated ways to do thus, such as type classes, GADTs, composition, et cetera, but this will get you started.

### Type class version

This is a different way to do it, which is more complicated.

Here is a plain type class version:

```
-- The robot type is expressed using a type parameter (called "a")
data Robot a = Robot {
    position :: Char,
    weight :: Int
}

-- All robot types have their own "makeAction" function
class RobotType a where
    makeAction :: Robot a -> String

data TRobot
instance RobotType TRobot where
    makeAction robot = ...

data FRobot
instance RobotType FRobot where
    makeAction robot = …
```

Note that `Robot TRobot` and `Robot FRobot` are *different types*, so if you need a generic robot type, you have to do it with existential types:

```
data AnyRobot = forall a. RobotType a => AnyRobot (Robot a)
```

Basically, because we are storing the difference between TRobot and FRobot in the type system, we need existential types to allow us to access those differences at runtime (since types are deleted at compile time).

Comment: I already made an implementation of makeAction with the following signature :
makeAction :: Robot -> String. 
So depending of the attributes of Robot, a different String is showed.
Knowing this, how would use typeclasses for the same problem?

Comment: With this approach, you don't; you just have `makeFRobot` and `makeTRobot` functions which initialize robots with different `makeAction` functions.

Comment: @Konstantinos: I've added a type class example.  See Paul Manta's answer for a more thorough explanation of the simpler method.

Comment: This seems to me like an example of the existential anti-pattern. I think it would probably be better to make the dictionary passing explicit in this case rather than use the implicit dictionary passing of type classes. If you are going to go this route though, it might be better to add some kind of restriction through constructors like with GADTs or the constructor functions that duplode mentioned.

Comment: @DavidYoung: I agree.  I would probably only use the typeclass version if I didn't need existential types.

Answer (score 15):

I have <insert object-oriented design here>. How do I implement this in a non-OO language such as Haskell?

Erm... that's not a very good idea. It would probably be far better to take a step back and explain *what* you are actually trying to achieve. Haskell requires a radically different way of thinking about software design. Without knowing what you actually want to do, it's difficult to say exactly what the best way to achieve it would be.

In particular: How are the two sorts of robot actually different? How are they similar?

It might be that you just want to constructors for a single datatype (as you have written), with a `move` function that behaves differently for each, and `take` / `drop` functions that don't care. Or maybe you want just *one* constructor, with a field that says which robot type it is. Or maybe you actually want two *completely separate* types. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, it's hard to say.

Comment: I wouldn't say Haskell is necessarily non-OO. You can do OO programming in Haskell, it's essentially just prototype-based rather than class-based.

Comment: @DavidYoung You can "do" functional programming in non-functional languages such as C or JavaScript. That does not make these "functional programming languages". ;-)

Comment: I realize that, but I would even go so far as to say that Haskell can be pretty effective at OO programming when it is done in the right way.

Comment: @DavidYoung My point is merely that Haskell is not _designed_ to support OOP, and that when writing code in Haskell, thinking in terms of objects and classes shouldn't be the starting point. I agree that such concepts _can_ be encoded, comparatively well perhaps. But that doesn't mean it's the best way to solve a programming problem.

Comment: That also doesn't mean that it *isn't* the best approach. I believe it depends on what problem is being solved. It's good to keep different styles in mind, just in case. In fact, I think what you describe in the last part of your answer is what I would consider good prototype-based OOP in Haskell.

Comment: My point was really that when a beginner shows up and starts asking how to do OOP in Haskell, the correct response is "learn the Haskell way". Learning how to encode foreign concepts into the language seems like trying to run before you can walk.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell doesn't have subtypes in the same way that OO languages do. Usually, if you need that kind of subtype polymorphism you use data types that have higher order functions as fields. It doesn't look like that's necessary in this case though.

Here is how I would approach it:

```
data RobotType = TRobot | FRobot
data Robot = Robot {
    robotType :: RobotType
   ,position  :: Char
   ,weight    :: Int
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, subclassing from imperative OO languages doesn't translate directly to Haskell. One particular way to define your specific example is this:

```
data Robot = Robot {
    position   :: Char,
    weight     :: Int
    makeAction :: -- Your function signature
}

makeTRobot :: Char -> Int -> Robot
makeTRobot p w = Robot { position = p,
                         weight = w,
                         makeAction = -- TRobot's action function }
```

Comment: @AndrewC I know it is just I wrapper, but I still think it's useful. The `action` field could be just an implementation detail that you don't export outside the module. Abstraction is fundamentally unnecessary, but that doesn't mean it's not useful.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, you're right. I figured out how silly what it was. I wasn't paying enough attention when I posted this.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), which is the primary way to do this kind of thing in OO languages, but Haskell doesn't support this.

Instead, Haskell accomplishes mostly the same thing using [typeclass polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). If you've never heard of this before, I'd suggest you read either [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) or [this](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html).

Since I actually want to answer your question, the way you'd get the behavior you are looking for is like this:

1. Create a typeclass that is similar to an abstract class that defines the minimum behavior that a type has to implement to be included in this typeclass:

   ```
   class Robot r where
       position :: r -> Char
       weight :: r -> Int
       makeAction :: -- ?? You didn't say.
   ```
2. Then make each of your types an instance of that typeclass:

   ```
   data FRobot = FRobot { frPosition :: Char, frWeight :: Int }

   instance Robot FRobot where
       position = frPosition
       weight = frWeight
       makeAction = -- Whatever you wanted.
   ```

Then do the same thing for your other types. After you've done this, you can use `Robot r => r -> ...` in your type signatures and have r be any kind of Robot. If you don't want to implement a certain method, you can define it as `error` or `undefined` but be warned that this is unsafe and undesirable behavior.

EDIT: If you want makeAction to have different types for different Robots... You'll probably be reduced to repetition as there's no way to easily fit that in to the type system otherwise. If you give us a bit more info, I might be able to suggest something more specific.

Comment: It is worth noting that if the OP does decide to use this solution, it will be harder for him to have a list of robots since they are all of a different type now.

Comment: `robotList :: Robot r => [r]`

Comment: Still, `Robot r => [r]` means robots within a single list have to have the same type.

Comment: That type signature will be able to hold any type of robot, but only one type. It cannot hold both `FRobot` and `TRobot`. The type signature would have to be something along the lines of `forall r. Robot r => [r]`, but now we're getting into tricky territory. (That type signature might be wrong, I'm not completely familiar with Haskell's `forall`.)

Comment: True. That is a tradeoff you have to make.

Comment: To make it work you need a few extensions. It's messy and you shouldn't do it. For more info on this problem see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787317/list-of-different-types) question.