# Filter by length

Tags: haskell

How I can make here filter `(x:xs) = (x, length (x:xs))` that puts length when length > 1?

Currently, if input is `abcaaabbb` output is `[('a',1),('b',1),('c',1),('a',3),('b',3)]`, but I'm looking for `abca3b3`.

My code:

```
import Data.List

encode :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
encode s = map go (group s)
               where go (x:xs) = (x, length (x:xs))

main = do
    s <- getLine
    print (encode s)
```

Last string will be `putStrLn (concat (map (\(x,y) -> x : [y]) (encode s)))` for convert list to string.

Comment: The `''` is no Char value. So, you would at least need `[('a', '0'),('b', '2')]` or `[('a', 0),('b', 2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am a newbie myself, this is probably not very haskellian. But you can do it about like this (xs as would be the list `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]`):

Create "a1b2a3":

```
concat $ map (\(c, l) -> c:(show l)) xs
```

Filter out 1s:

```
filter (\x -> x /= '1') "a1b2a3"
```

will give you "ab2a3"

Comment: or, combine both `concat $ map (\(c,l) -> c:(if l==1 then "" else show l))`

Comment: @karakfa thank you so much. Your answer is better, because with tokosh algorithm if I have `"aaaaaaaaaaaa"` result is `a2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a list like this in Haskell:

```
[('a'),('b'),('c'),('a',3),('b',3)]
```

Each element if a list needs to have the same type in haskell, and ('c') [('a') :: Char] and ('b',3) [('a',1) :: Num t => (Char, t)] are different types.

Maybe also have a look at [List of different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787317/list-of-different-types)

I would suggest, that you change your list to a (Char, Maybe num) datastructure.

**Edit:**

From your new question, I think you have been searching for this:

```
import Data.List

encode :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
encode s = map go (group s)
               where go (x:xs) = (x, length (x:xs))

f :: (Char, Int) -> String
f (a, b) = if b == 1 then [a] else [a] ++ show b

encode2 :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
encode2 [] = []
encode2 (x:xs) = f(x) ++ encode2 xs

main = do
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn $ encode2 $ encode s
```

Comment: `num` is not a type, not even `char`

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are right. I refered to the fact, that :t ('a',1) returns ('a',1) :: Num t => (Char, t). Didn't wanted to make it to long. I will update it.

Comment: @pertpoert: Hope that tokosh or mine solution answers your question now?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this suits your needs, but if you do not need filtering, this does the work:

```
encode::String -> String
encode "" = ""
encode (x:xs) = doIt0 xs x 1 where
        doIt0 [] ch currentPos = [ch]++showPos currentPos
        doIt0 (x:xs) ch currentPos
                |x==ch = doIt0 xs ch $ currentPos+1
                |otherwise= [ch]++ (showPos currentPos) ++ (doIt0 xs x 1)
        showPos pos = if pos> 1 then show pos else ""

main = do
        s <- getLine
        print (encode s)
```