# Lists of mixed types using wrappers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to make a list of mixed types by wrapping the types with a another type?

As an example, if I have two data types, `Cat` and `Dog`, can I make a list of both cats and dogs using something like a `Pet` wrapper? I know that this can be done using algebraic data types, but I would also like other wrappers to be available, such as `Animal`.

The basic way I want to use this is below:

```
data Cat = Cat
data Dog = Dog
data Cow = Cow

data Pet a = Pet a
data Animal a = Animal a

pets = [Pet Cat, Pet Dog]
animals = [Animal Cat, Animal Dog, Animal Cow]
```

Is there a way to do this? I was also considering if typeclasses could be used.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787317/list-of-different-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You'd use something like this:

```
data Pet = ItsACat Cat | ItsADog Dog

pets = [ItsACat Cat, ItsADog Dog]
```

Comment: I suppose this is a good solution, I'm just concerned about the scalability of algebraic data types if there are a lot of possible pet or animal types.