# Haskell - Tuples of custom types

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to represent tuples of custom types. What I cam up with is as follows:

```
type Name = String

data DataType a  = DataType a deriving Show

data Val a = Single (DataType a) | List [(DataType a)] deriving Show

data State a = State [(Name,(Val a))] deriving Show

append :: (Name, (Val a)) -> State a -> State a
append nv (State st) = State (st ++ [nv])
```

Now the problem is that State cannot be [("NUM1",Single (DataType 1)), ("STR1",Single (DataType "Hello"))]. I want to be able to perform the following:

```
*Main> num1 = Single (DataType 1)
*Main> num1
Single (DataType 1)
*Main> str1 = Single (DataType "str1")
*Main> str1
Single (DataType "str1")
*Main> st1 = append ("NUM1",num1) (State [])
*Main> st1
State [("NUM1",Single (DataType 1))]
*Main> st2 = append ("STR1",str1) st1

<interactive>:8:28: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘st1’
    • In the second argument of ‘append’, namely ‘st1’
      In the expression: append ("STR1", str1) st1
      In an equation for ‘st2’: st2 = append ("STR1", str1) st1
```

Haskell complains when I try to append a `(Name, Val String)` because it has already interpreted `State` as `State [(Name, (Val Int)]`, which is not really my intention.

How do I achieve the `State` to act as dictionary for the DataType Int or DataType String?

PS:
One possible use of such a functionality is in generated code, where the more than one types are generated as code and it also uses the functionality above to represent state.
For example the user could define some types using a UI, then a system generates Haskell code for those types along with the `state` defined above.

Comment: Assuming you could build such a mixed-type value, what would you do with it? Please show intended usage.

Comment: You may be able to get away with [universal quantification](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.00/docs/set/universal-quantification.html) not sure though...

Comment: @n.m. I have added an intended use case

Comment: Your use case description is too general to be useful. Please show some specific (non-working) (pseudo) code that uses your data type.

Answer (score 5):

Mixed type lists aren't really supported in Haskell, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787429/3953988 has some good solutions.

From that answer, either:

- create a new container type that is a sum (eg: `data DataType = X Int | Y String...`)
- use existential types (eg: `data DataType = forall a. Show a => Datatype a`) (Show being an optional constraint, which I think you want given you want DataType to be showable)

Comment: The latter is isomorphic to `data DataType = DataType String`. It is sometimes considered to be an [antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).